# ag-grid mutli-checkbox disable second on selecting first

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I used ag-grid-angular . 
For checkbox I added

```
cellRendererFramework: AgGridCheckboxComponent
```

In ag-grid-checkbox component it I have to add a logic like when I select **Exempted** then checkbox of **Validated Exempted** should be disabled.

[image]

I have added condition

```
if (selectedKey == 'onBoardExempted ') {

 params.data.onBoardExempted = params.value;

 }
```

in html is have added

```
[disabled]="isDisable"
```

No idea where to use this disable condition for **ValidationExempted**

Comment: honestly, your question is all over the place and leaves us to do guesswork. please post relevant code, relevant meaning not relevant line but something that is useful for us to answer

Comment: I understand the question. Working on it